# How to include density coloring in pairwise correlation scatter plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse, ggally

I have the following code:

```
library(GGally)
library(nycflights13)
library(tidyverse)

dat <- nycflights13::flights %>% 
       select(dep_time, sched_dep_time, dep_delay,  arr_time, sched_arr_time, arr_delay)  %>% 
       sample_frac(0.01)
dat
ggpairs(dat)
```

It produces this:

[image]

How can I add the density coloring so that it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: How about using ggpairs(dat, lower = list(continuous = "density"))?

Comment: @ed_sans Not what I want exactly. Need scatter plot like correlation as in OP.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using ideas from [How to reproduce smoothScatter's outlier plotting in ggplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13094827/how-to-reproduce-smoothscatters-outlier-plotting-in-ggplot) , [R - Smoothing color and adding a legend to a scatterplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20085375/r-smoothing-color-and-adding-a-legend-to-a-scatterplot), and [How to use loess method in GGally::ggpairs using wrap function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35085261/how-to-use-loess-method-in-ggallyggpairs-using-wrap-function) you can define your own function to pass to ggpairs.

```
my_fn <- function(data, mapping, ...){
      p <- ggplot(data = data, mapping = mapping) + 
        stat_density2d(aes(fill=..density..), geom="tile", contour = FALSE) +
        scale_fill_gradientn(colours=rainbow(100))
      p
}

ggpairs(dat, lower=list(continuous=my_fn))
```

**EDIT**

*From comment: How do you add histogram in the diagonal and remove "Corr:" in the correlation value?*

You can set the `diag`onal and `upper` arguments. So to add the histogram (assuming you mean `geom_histogram`) you can use `diag=list(continuous=wrap("barDiag", binwidth=100))` and to remove the correlation completely use `upper=list(continuous="blank")`. If you want to  actually remove the text `*corr:*`, you will need to define a new function - please see the function `cor_fun` at [Change colors in ggpairs now that params is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37889222/change-colors-in-ggpairs-now-that-params-is-deprecated?answertab=votes#tab-top) .

So your plot becomes

```
ggpairs(dat, lower=list(continuous=my_fn),
        diag=list(continuous=wrap("barDiag", binwidth=100)),
        upper=list(continuous=wrap(cor_fun, sz=10, stars=FALSE))
        )
```

[image]

**EDIT**

*From comment: How do you color the diagonal histogram like in OP?*

To colour just add the relevant arguments to the `barDiag` function, in this case `fill` and `colour`. So `diag` would then be

```
diag=list(continuous=wrap("barDiag", binwidth=100, fill="brown", col="black"))
```

(`fill` gives the main colour, and `col` gives the colour to outline the bars)

Comment: Thanks a lot. How do you add histogram in the diagonal and remove "Corr:" in the correlation value?

Comment: Would you mind to add also the resulting graph to your answer, please?

Comment: @user20650 great answer. how do you color the diagonal histogram like in OP?

Comment: @user20650 Would you mind looking at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44984822/how-to-create-lower-density-plot-using-your-own-function-in-ggally